# convolution of two normal bivariate

Tags: convolution

i need to perform the convolution of two normal vibariate. I defined

```
a = {Subscript[\[Sigma], 11], Subscript[\[Sigma], 21]}
b = {Subscript[\[Sigma], 12], Subscript[\[Sigma], 22]}
B1=PDF[BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, a, Subscript[\[Rho], 1]], {x, y}]
B2=PDF[BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, b, Subscript[\[Rho], 1]], {x, y}]
```

Could you please help me to move forward ? I tried to understand how to perform a 2D convolution in mathematica, without much success.

Thank you,
Andrea

Answer (score 2):

No need to resort to numerical convolution for this classic problem.  In 1D:

```
Convolve[
 PDF[NormalDistribution[m1, s1], x], 
 PDF[NormalDistribution[m2, s2], y], 
 x, y]
```

and likewise in 2D.

Answer (score 0):

sorry i think i found the answer

```
A[x, y] = 
  PDF[BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, a, Subscript[\[Rho], 1]], {x, y}];
B[x, y] = 
  PDF[BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, a, Subscript[\[Rho], 2]], {x, y}];
test[t, z] = N[Convolve[A[x, y], B[x, y], {x, y}, {t, z}]]
```

Best regards,
Andrea